# Steps to update Joomla 1.5 component to Joomla 2.5 component

Tags: php, joomla, components, upgrade, joomla2.5

Please provide me steps to update Joomla 1.5 component to Joomla 2.5 component.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [upgrade Joomla 1.5 components to Joomla 2.5 components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453033/upgrade-joomla-1-5-components-to-joomla-2-5-components)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is much to be learned at [Adapting from 1.5 to 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6), and from [this DVLancer blog](http://dvlancer.com/blog/1-blog/33-migrating-joomla-extensions-from-version-15-to-joomla-25.html):

***Global variables $mainframe and $option***

**Joomla 1.5**

```
global $mainframe, $option;
```

**Joomla 2.5** replaced with

```
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
$option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
```

or

```
$option = $this->option //If the code is in a controller class derived from JControllerForm
```

**Get page title within a template***

**Joomla 1.5**

```
global $mainframe;
$mainframe = &JFactory::getApplication();
$page_title = $mainframe->getPageTitle();
```

**in Joomla 2.5 replaced with**

```
$app =& JFactory::getDocument();
$page_title = $app->getTitle();
```

***Template Path***

**Joomla 1.5

```
"templates/templatename/"
```

**Joomla 2.5**

```
$app= & JFactory::getApplication();
$template = $app->getTemplate();
```

**or**

```
"templates/".$this->template."/"
```

***How to find out if you are on the homepage***

**Joomla 1.5**

```
if( JRequest::getVar('view') == "frontpage" ) {
  // You are on the home page
} else {
  // You are not 
}
```

**Joomla 2.5**

```
$menu =& JSite::getMenu(); // get the menu
$active = $menu->getActive(); // get the current active menu
if ( $active->home == 1 ) { // check if this is the homepage
  // You are on the home page
} else {
  // You are not
}
```

***Accessing Error Variables***

**Joomla 1.5**

```
$code = $this->error->code;
$message = $this->error->message;
```

In **Joomla 2.5** those variable are now private and have to be accessed via getter methods to avoid the following error: 
`PHP cannot acess protected property error`

```
$code = $this->error->getCode();
$message = $this->error->getMessage();
```