# Joomla custom component migration from 1.5 to 2.5

Tags: joomla-extensions

I have migrated my site from Joomla 1.5 to Joomla 2.5. There is a custom component developed by 3rd party which is not working properly in Joomla 2.5. 
Now, I am facing challenges to get this done in the new version. I am not aware of the functions used in the component that are not working or throwing errors.

Can anyone share a list of Joomla 1.5 component development functions which are deprecated in Joomla 2.5 or should be updated?

For e.g. see the following functions/variable:

```
global $mainframe; // In Joomla 1.5

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication(); // In Joomla 2.5
```

I just want to make myself more clear that I am looking for joomla custom component migration from 1.5 to 2.5. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you find some usefull links but first here are some thoughts **from my experience:**

- If your component is a state of the art Joomla 1.5 component, upgrading it to 2.5 won't be so hard (some / most components are not so well coded).
- Think / search for a replacement that already works in 2.5, it may save you the trouble
- Consider redoing / rethinking the whole component having in mind current web development standards / trends, changes to the Joomla! API.

[Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 1.6](http://docs.joomla.org/Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6)

[Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 2.5 and Joomla Platform 11.4](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_2.5_and_Joomla_Platform_11.4)

[Steps to update Joomla 1.5 component to Joomla 2.5 component [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505574/steps-to-update-joomla-1-5-component-to-joomla-2-5-component)

Comment: Hi Valentin, Thank you for sharing these links but I have already gone through these. I have also checked Joomla Community(forum) but many questions are unanswered. Actually the component was developed by 3rd party. I am just now involved in the migration process. I am doing debugging and modifying the code to get it working. So not aware/sure if the functions/code used in component development is no longer in use now. Just doing my best. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Next thing to do is to ask more specific questions like I have this, it does this think, what can I do in 2.5. The thing is you must be specific in order to get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input.