# How big is the pain upgrading custom made components, modules and plugins to new joomla versions?

Tags: joomla, migration, upgrade

what are your experiences doing upgrades with custom modules, plugins and components?

[I read this post here about upgrading components from 1.5 to 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758399/joomla-custom-component-migration-from-1-5-to-2-5)

and honestly, it gives me shivers. If I am going to develop solutions for small enterprises (which joomla seems?? to be the best option) and my customer is coming in 2 years complaining about he has to move to a new version because of security breaches or missing support of other extensions... what am I gonna tell him?

Answer (score 2):

You're client is absolutely right. Joomla 1.5 is old, not as secure by far and is not supported by anymore anymore. Once you have upgraded to Joomla 2.5, upgrade to Joomla 3.2. From then on, future upgrades will be far more simple.

Yes, upgrading a site from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 can be a bit complex, however it all depends on the extensions you're using. Firstly, you should check all the 3rd party extensions you're using to see if the developer has released a Joomla 2.5 compatible version. If there are a few that aren't, then seek some alternatives.

As a developer, be sure to charge for a service like this as in most cases, it's not an easy task. Also be sure to tell your client that if there isn't a 2.5 compatible version of any extension, an alternative will have to be used.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the extension. I did some that were really easy and some were really hard and not worth doing ... it's so much easier to build an extension in 2.5/3 that a lot of times it is easier to redo from scratch rather than spend hours tracing out all the implications of the use of deprecated code.  Further, if you have a third party extension in 1.5 that does not have a 2.5 version that means the developer is probably not very active in keeping things up to date (not always but probably) and I would be concerned about security and php 5.4/5.5 support anyway.    Another thing is that in 2.5+ you often need fewer extensions than you did in 1.5 because some of the obvious missing pieces are now included (user profile plugins, alternate layouts, access control, multilingual support, and in 3 tags and versioning).  The biggest problem is if you have an old extension that was a fake 1.5 extension meaning that it was a 1.0 extension that basically worked around the need for the legacy plugin by doing the legacy functions itself.

Answer (score 1):

Regular updates are normal practice when it comes to any web or computer system (not just Joomla). Updates can be security patches, new functionality or for other reasons.

As new features are implemented, there can often be issues with backwards compatibility and sometimes a point is reached where it makes sense to release a new version without the backwards compatibility baggage.

The migration from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 was relatively traumatic but moving from Joomla 2.5 to 3.x will be easier and hopefully this will also apply to updates beyond Joomla 3.x.

In terms of client expectations, it is probably wise to explain to clients that there is an ongoing cost to maintain a website and they should budget accordingly. This is no different to the operating system on a computer, otherwise we'd all still be using Windows 3.1 or similar!

You can minimise future migration pain by sticking to the core Joomla functionality as much as possible, minimising the number of third party extensions and where necessary by choosing popular and well supported third party extensions from established developers. Some developers provided excellent instructions and created migration scripts etc. to help with the migration from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 while other developers left clients to fend for themselves. Take this into account when choosing extensions.